Complex regular representation of $\mathbb{C}C_n$.
Doing a representation theory course at uni and I really don't get how regular representations (or deriving representations from an action in general work at all)
The question on the sheet is "Explicitly decompose the complex regular representation $\mathbb{C}C_n$ as a direct sum of irreducible subrepresentations." I know this question is already on Stack Exchange, but I really don't understand what's going on.
I kinda already have this:

$\mathbb{C}C_n$ is the set of all functions $f: C_n \to \mathbb{C}$
The left regular representation of $\mathbb{C}C_n$ is $\rho: C_n \to \mathbb{C}C_n$, and $ (\rho(g)f)(x)) = f(g^{-1}(x))$ , so $\rho(r^m) f(r^n) = f(r^{n-m})$ (taking $C_n = \langle r \rangle$).
A subrepresentation of this, is a representation of $G=C_n$ on a $G$-invariant subspace of $\mathbb{C}C_n$. These are subspaces $W$ of $\mathbb{C}C_n$ such that $\rho(g)(W)\subseteq W$ for all $g \in C_n$. So these are spaces of functions for which for all $f(x)\in W$, $f(g^{-1}x) \in W$ for all $g \in C_n$. Thus these are sets of functions $\{f_i\}_{i\in I}$ from $C_n$ to $\mathbb{C}$ such that $f_i(r^k) = f_j(e)$ for some $j$, for all $k \leq n$.
One such subspace is the set $\{f: C_n \to \mathbb{C}; r^i \mapsto \omega^i, \omega^n = 1\}$?

This is really confusing me! Have I already gone wrong (I suspect I may have) and can I have a hint as to where to go from here. This is a layer too deep for me it seems!

Your item 3 looks a bit off. I find it strange to index all the functions in a space $W$. At some point you need to use a basis for $W$. In the case of the cyclic group it turns out that you get away with 1-dimensional subspaces, so specifying a basis is simple. You are then looking for functions $f$ such that $\rho(g)(f)=z f$ for some constant $z=z(g)\in\Bbb{C}$ (that can depend on $g$). Yet in other words $(\rho(g)f)(x)=z(g) f(x)$ for all $x\in C_n$.

And in item 4 you are looking at the 1-dimensional space spanned by the given $f$.

Anyway, you could start with the simple case of $n=2$. Can you show that in this case $\Bbb{C}C_2$ splits into a direct sum $W_+\oplus W_-$ (both 1-dimensional), where
$$W_+={f:C_2\to\Bbb{C}\mid f(r)=f(1)}$$
and
$$W_-={f:C_2\to\Bbb{C}\mid f(r)=-f(1)}?$$
Show that $\rho(r)(f)=f$ for all $f\in W_+$ and $\rho(r)(f)=-f$ for all $f\in W_-$.

@JyrkiLahtonen Hi, thanks for your comments! Why is it true that we are looking for $\rho(g)(f) = zf$ for some $z(g) \in \mathbb{C}$? How does this follow from the more familiar $f(g^{-1}(x))\in W$ for all $g \in G$.

That is a good question. I jumped forward a bit at that point. It goes that way if and only if $\dim W=1$, when $W$ is spanned by any non-zero function in it. I knew that  representations of cyclic groups (the same applies to all finite abelian groups) are direct sums of 1-dimensional subrepresentations, so we can do it in this case.

My 3rd comment may be more useful. I may be wrong, but it looks like you are not used to playing with vector spaces consisting of functions.

How did you guess! haha We did a first course in LA last year which I was okay at but didn't focus on vector spaces of functions (apart from dual spaces) much at all so this is a pretty big jump for me. I think I also am pretty rusty even on that too. I understand your third comment though.

Thank you so much!

The next case is with $n=3$. This time you get three subspaces indexed by $\ell\in{0,1,2}$:
$$W_\ell={f:C_3\to\Bbb{C}\mid f(rx)=\omega^\ell f(x)\ \text{for all $x\in C_3$}}.$$
Here $\omega=e^{2\pi i/3}$. The next step generalizes this to all $n$ with adjusted $\omega$ and range of the parameter $\ell$.

This tries to be a short answer (short w.r.t. my own settings), and its main part is to explain and use an equivalent notation that makes thins easier to digest and compute.
Here is the equivalent setting. The cyclic group $(C_n, +)$ has the elements $0,1,2,\dots$ which are integers always taken modulo $n$, it is generated by $1$. The group ring $R=\Bbb C[C_n]$ is the set of all linear combinations with complex coefficients in the "symbols" $[0]$, $[1]$, $[2]$, and so on. The ring structure is given by
$$
[j]\cdot [k] :=[j+k]\ ,
$$
where the central dot is multiplication in the group ring $R$, and the plus is addition in $C_n$. We extend the above law by linearity.
Such a linear combination is of the shape
$$\tag{*}$$
$$
\begin{aligned}
c &= c_0[0] + c_1[1] + c_2 [2] +\dots c_{n-1}[n-1]\\
&= c_0[1]^0 + c_1[1]^1 + c_2 [1]^2 +\dots c_{n-1}[1]^{n-1}\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
The unit in the ring $R$ is $[0]$ because $[0][k]=[0+k]=[k]$, so by linearity / by linear extension $[0]\cdot c=c$. I will avoid to write something like "$1=[0]$", so always read $[0]$ as being the unit in the ring $R$.
There is a map $C_n\to R$ given by $k\to [k]$, and by definition the addition in $C_n$ is (through this map) compatible with the multiplication in $R$. This is the regular representation. (When using functions, the scalars from a linear combination as the above are collected and reassembled to a function, so $c = c_0[0] + c_1[1] + c_2 [2] +\dots c_{n-1}[n-1]$ is equivalently seen as a function $k\to c_k$.)
Writing elements of $R$ as in $(*)$ makes it also simpler to see $R$ (through the forgetful functor) as a vector space $V$ over $\Bbb C$ of dimension $n$, since elements come already written as linear combinations in the basis $[0]$, $[1]$, $[2]$, ... $[n-1]$.
It remains to find invariant subspaces of $V$. If the action of $[1]$ on a subspace $W\subseteq V$ lets it invariant, then it is invariant, because each other symbol $[k]$ is a repeated action of $[1]$. It turns out, that we easily write down such $W$'s of dimension one, obtained as "spaces where $[1]$ acts as a complex root $w$ of the unit of order $n$, so $w\in \Bbb C$, $w^n=1$. There are $n$ such complex numbers, for each one define
$$
W(w) = \Bbb C\cdot\underbrace{([0] + \bar w[1] + \bar w^2[2]+\dots)}_{\text{Notation for this "vector": }v(w)}\ .
$$
Here $\bar w=1/w$, since each $w$ has modulus one.
And indeed, $[1]\cdot v(w)=[1] + \bar w[2] + \bar w^2[3]+\dots)
=w(\bar w[1] + \bar w^2[2]+ \bar w^3[3]+\dots)=w\cdot v(w)$.
So $W(w)$ is invariated by the action of $C_n$. It turns out that the vectors $v(w)$, for $w$ running among the unit roots of order $n$, are a basis for $V$. This is so, since the matrix of their coefficients has a non-zero determinant. More exactly, if $\omega$ is a primitive root of order $n$ of the unit, then  all $w$'s are $1,\omega,\omega^2,\dots,\omega^{n-1}$, and the corresponding matrix is a Vandermonde matrix with these values on the first row and on the first column. An alternative argument is the fact that the vectors $(v(w))_w$ are $n$ eigenvectors to $n$ different eigenvalues $(w)_w$ for the linear map "left multiplication by $[1]$" seen as a linear map $V\to V$. This shows:
$$
V =\bigoplus_{w}W(w) =\bigoplus_{w}\Bbb C\cdot v(w)=\bigoplus_{w}
V^{[1]=w}\ .
$$
Here, $V^{[1]=w}$ is a notation for the space of vectors, on which $[1]$ acts as multiplication by the scalar $w$.
